# AutoMapper does not contain a definition for 'Reset'

Tags: automapper, automapper-10

I have upgraded my AutoMapper version from 7 to 10-beta5.

As part of C# Xunit, I have to reset the Automapper. But, after upgrading to 10, getting an error:

> AutoMapper does not contain a definition for 'Reset'

Let me know what is the alternate method for rest in Automapper version 10?

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Configuration.html

Comment: Thanks @LucianBargaoanu